# how to check while job has not run

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table in which i have some data related to oracle job which executes some procedures.Here is the query and data format.

```
SELECT SRLNUM, TABLE_NAME, PURPOSE, LAST_UPDATE, DUR,
TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (LAST_UPDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')+ DUR / (24 * 60) RUNTIME
FROM V_DASHJOBS
```

Here is the data of table which have job details

[image]

Question is that is there any way that i can detect using query that job has not still run on its `RUNTIME` and also if job has not run on its `RUNTIME` then flag `0` should return and if has run then `1` should return.

I am calculating `RUNTIME` by adding DUR to last_update and also i want to give a relax of 30 minutes to job that job can be run 30 minute late from actual runtime

Comment: when you say it has not run on it run time have you saved anywhere the exact time of its run? can you give me the snapshot of one data set?

Comment: No I am calculating run time by adding `DUR` to `last_update` and also i want to give a relax of 30 minutes to job that job can be run 30 minute late from actual runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do arithmetic with Oracle's DATE datatype, so your calculation of RUNTIME is too complex.

This query takes your query and adds a CASE statement to compare the derived RUNTIME with the current datetime.  If I have properly understood your requirement, this will allow you to determine whether a job has run as scheduled.

```
with data as (
    SELECT SRLNUM
          , TABLE_NAME
          , PURPOSE
          , LAST_UPDATE
          , DUR
          , LAST_UPDATE+ (DUR / (24 * 60)) RUNTIME
    FROM V_DASHJOBS )
select data.*
       , case when sysdate < data.runtime then 1 else 0 end as haz_run
       , case when sysdate < data.runtime + (1/48) then 1 else 0 end as haz_run_with_slack
from data
/
```

The second CASE() statements adds an extra half-hour to the derived runtime, to allow for your supplementary requirement, "that job can be run 30 minute late from actual runtime".

Comment: @user1915635 = please read your own question, specifically the paragraph after the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this to get the difference between the times.

```
select (last_update+ duration/1440) - last_update  from dual;
```

hoping that the duration is time in minutes.